# Update Nested Counter in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I am going through a large CSV file line by line. What I want to do is count occurrences of the strings in a certain column. Where I am running into trouble is that I would like the counter to be nested inside of a dictionary, where the keys for the outer dictionary is the value from another column. I need to do this or else the data will be processed incorrectly as there are duplicates.

imagine my CSV:

```
outerDictKey    CounterKey
apple     purple
apple     blue
pear    purple
```

So basically I want:

```
dictionary = { apple:
                    counter({blue: 1
                     purple: 1})
                pear:
                   counter({purple: 1})
             }
```

I wasnt sure how to do this.

```
myCounter = Counter()
myKey = 'barbara'
counterKey = 'streisand'
largeDict = defaultdict(dict)       
largeDict[myKey] = {myCounter[counterKey] += 1}
```

Intuitively this looks like it wouldnt work, and of course it gives a syntax error.

I also tried

```
largeDict[myKey][myCounter][counterKey]+=1
```

Which throws a "TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'" error.

Finally

```
>>> largeDict[myKey]=Counter()
>>> largeDict[myKey][myCounter][counterKey]+=1
```

Which still gives a type error. So how do I increment a Counter nested in a dictionary?

Comment: So the outer dictionary contains counters *directly*?

Comment: When you use a key for the outer dictionary, I would like it to give you a Counter. By increment I mean "look up the string in the counter and add 1". So every time it finds the word 'apple', it looks up 'apple' in the counter and adds one

Comment: Why not just use `defaultdict(Counter)` then? You are overcomplicating matters. Then you just do `largeDict['columnkey']['thing-you-want-count'] += 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
myCounter = Counter()
largedict = { myKey:
                    {counterKey: myCounter
                     anotherKey: Value2}
             }

largedict[myKey][counterKey]['somethingyouwanttocount']+=1
```

`Counter` is just a dict with some extra functionality. However, as a dict, it cannot be a key in a dict, nor an entry in a set, which explains the unhashable exception.

Alternatively, if you're keeping track of information about coherent entities, rather than using nested `dicts`, you could store the information (including the counter) in objects, and put the objects in a `dict` as necessary.

If *every* value is a counter, then just use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
largedict = defaultdict(Counter)
largedict['apple']['purple']+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to `count occurrences of the strings in a certain column`, wouldnt this be enough

```
import collections
data = "Welcome to stack overflow. To give is to get."

print collections.Counter(data.split())
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'to': 2, 'give': 1, 'get.': 1, 'is': 1, 'Welcome': 1, 'To': 1, 'overflow.': 1, 'stack': 1})
```

Comment: Well there is more going on here but to keep it simple I left a lot of it out of the post. I am using info from other columns as keys and I need to do this or else the data will be processed incorrectly because  of duplicate. Thank you though

Comment: Could you please explain this in detail in your question? People might be able to come up with creative solutions :)